# Как находить совпадения в % соотношении?

Tags: php

Интересует решение поиска совпадений например по номеру телефона:

Случается так что номер телефона отличается только первой цифрой

в базе

89066663322
или так
9066663322

а например с телефонии приходит

79066663322

Отличие очень маленькое хочется поиск сделать в % соотношении.

Например: поступил звонок в базе есть номер телефона как в примере выше с 8, а с телефонии пришло с 7 и надо чтобы указал совпадение 98% и человек может выбрать привязать или нет к контакту.

**Какое-то может решение есть хорошее?**

Comment: убираем код страны, и сравниваем по каждому символу отдельно, но будут проценты с шагом примерно в 10 % для стран у которых 1-значный код

Comment: А в Росси номер 89066663322,79066663322 и +79066663322 это одно и тоже?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как минимум есть 2 неплохие built-in функции(*взято из мануала по пхп*):

- [Расстояние Левенштейна](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.levenshtein.php) - `levenshtein($str1, $str2)`вычисляет минимальное количество вставок, замен и удалений символов, необходимое для преобразования str1 в str2.
- [Похожесть строк](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.similar-text.php) - `similar_text($str1, $str2, $percent)`вычисляет разницу в символах между двумя строками, и возвращает в 3й аргумент его процентное значение.

[Более детальный пост на Habr'e](https://habrahabr.ru/post/114997/)(Впрочем идет немного вразрез с основным вопросом, хотя все еще неплохо описывает способы и алгоритмы *нечеткого сравнения*)

Answer (score 2):

Предлагаю вам отделить международный код и сам номер и вносить в БД их раздельно. При проверке разделять входящий номер на код и номер, и проверять соответственно будет легче. Процентное соотношение на совпадение это совсем не решает вопрос. Как пример, мобильные номера в России состоят из 10 цифр, отделите от входящего значения последние 10 цифр, остаток и будет международный код, а там в зависимости от +7 или 8 прописываете поведение решения задачи.